# Advice on how to stop task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I'm not a multithreading expert, just beginner so please try to understand my poor understanding of the subject.

I have some tasks executing them asynchronously with [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which is created with this bean :

```
<bean id="executorService" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors"
    factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">
    <constructor-arg value="10" />
</bean>
```

I'm submitting my tasks like this :

```
Future<String> resultHandler = executorService.submit(new WorkerClass());
```

Let's imagine scenarion where I would have 2 tasks running at the same time, task `A` and task `B`.

How would one stop just task `B` without making an impact to task `A`?

What would be wise to save to where, meaning should I create some kind of `HashMap` or something to store my Future objects and retrieve them via some key and doing `cancel(true)` on them or how would someone more experienced do this?

Comment: A `HashMap` of worker objects sounds good. You can interrupt the thread object, and handle the `InterruptedException` cleanly.

Comment: what about object cleanup from the `HashMap`or `ConcurrentHashMap`. Should I remove them from the map once they're done/interrupted/canceled or that is unnecessary?

Comment: If you don't need them anymore, clean them up.

Comment: Yeah, remove them from the `HashMap`, once the thread has died (reached the end of `run()`), and there is no reference to the `Worker`, all resources will be GCed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Future<String> resultHandlerB = executorService.submit(new WorkerClass());
...
boolean canceled=resultHandlerB.cancel(true);
```

Comment: I don't have resultHandlerA and resultHandlerB. I use same object variable for both

Comment: You cannot use same variable to hold 2 values. It holds only one, referring to either task A or task B, and you just lost reference to another, and cannot control it in any way. Was it your intention?

Comment: actually I managed to get it working using same variable in my map.  thanks